# How can I realize fullpage scrolling with static block?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create gallery block like on this page: https://www.aloyoga.com/collections/sale/products/w9173r-ambient-bra-s
I can't realize how to make block with description static while page is scrolling in the middle and not static when we scrolling at the top or at the bottom.
I'm looking for any ideas or realized plugins for this (not only woocommerce, pure js is ok too).

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to edit CSS of your theme, you could add following lines in **style** of Description

```
{position : sticky;
top : 20px;
right : 20px;
}
```

Experiment with the `top :` and `right :` to adjust the **location** of Description.